# Projectile with three objects

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, projectile, drag

The [Wikipedia page on ballistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistics) shows three projectiles thrown at the same angle in the same medium with same velocity. If that is so, then why does one object moves with a greater height and longer horizontal distance than the other two objects?

The other two objects are under the influence of viscous drag (the page says like that). Why is that viscous drag not applicable to first object?

Comment: Did you read the caption under the image?

Comment: Yes I did.But it didn't say if it was in the same medium or not.

Comment: It is three cases of projectiles in different media shown in a single graph.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to this image:

[image: Trajectories]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Inclinedthrow.gif)

The image is intended to show the effect that aerodynamic drag has on the motion of a projectile. The black curve shows the trajectory if there is no drag. This would be the trajectory in a vacuum e.g. if you fired the projectile on the Moon. This trajectory is a parabola.

Aerodynamic drag is proportional to velocity if the fluid flow is non-turbulent and the drag is dominated by viscous forces. Technically this means the Reynold's number is low. The blue line shows what would happen in this case, though it's hard to see that this would ever happen in practice. Possibly this type of trajectory might be observed on a very low gravity planet with a thin atmosphere. This regime is described by Stokes' law so it's known as Stokes' drag.

Under most circumstances the drag is dominated by inertial forces i.e. by the force required to accelerate the air out of the way of the projectile. In this case the drag is proportional to velocity squared, and this is shown by the green curve. This type of drag is typical for projectiles on Earth, and it's known as Newtonian drag.